# UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u016b' in position 1360: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python, utf-8, latin1

I wat to print the array eponym but i get this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u016b' in
>   position 1360: ordinal not in range(256)

This is my code

```
with codecs.open(epoFitx,encoding="utf-8") as fitx:
    for line in fitx:
        line = line.strip()
        eponimo.insert(len(eponimo), line.lower())
        print("    ", eponimo)
```

This is what I obtain:

> ['roux', 'tourette', 'sulzberger', 'mortimer', 'galeazzi', 'antley',
>   'henseleit', 'larsen', 'levret', 'bailey', 'schlemm', 'winegrad',
>   'hoover', 'klein', 'klatskin', 'uhl', 'codman', 'ober', 'b?hme',
>   'schonberg', 'anitschkow', 'c?stan', 'browne', 'albarran', 'ochsner',
>   'salzmann', 'cauchois', 'pette', 'michaelis', 'besredka', 'foix',
>   'bernhardt', 'cruchet', 'wilkins', 'benedict', 'pezzi', 'steinert',
>   'am?ndola', 'canga', 'oguchi', 'len?gre', 'arndt', 'bennett',
>   'bagolini', 'morrow', 'politzer', 'w?lfler', 'salomon', 'giaccai',
>   'dimitri', 'crowe', 'cockett', 'erdheim', 'steele']